# Is there a way to select multiple assets in a component?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sightly

I have a component that allows users to select an asset in a specified path. After users select the asset and click OK, I grab the lat/long from the asset's properties and plot it on a google map. This works fine but now I want the user to be able to select multiple assets so that multiple markers could be placed on the map.

Currently the dialog where the author selects the asset looks like this

[image]

Once the asset is selected and OK is clicked, my java code gets reference to this asset like this

```
public class Foo extends WCMUse {
   public void activate() {
      fileReference = getProperties().get("fileReference", String.class);
      ....
   }
}
```

**Question**
Is there a way to modify the code such that the user can select multiple assets rather than just being able to select one? And can I get access to all the selected assets in my Java class?

My `dialog.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Tab">
                    <items
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <asset-reference
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="Foo Bar:"
                                fieldDescription="Select the asset under /content/dam/foo-sync"
                                name="./fileReference"
                                xtype="pathfield"
                                rootPath="/content/dam/foo"/>
                    </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

`.context.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="My Component"
    allowedParents="*/parsys"
    componentGroup="My Components"/>
```

`_cq_editConfig.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <fileReference
            jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
            accept="[text/.*]"
            groups="[media]"
            propertyName="./fileReference"/>
    </cq:dropTargets>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to modify the code such that the user can select
>   multiple assets rather than just being able to select one?

Yes. You might consider using a "`multifield`" with `pathfield` instead of using only a `pathfield`".

```
asset-reference (xtype = multifield , name= ./fileReference)
       fieldConfig (xtype = pathfield)
```

> And can I get access to all the selected assets in my Java class?

In your java class , instead of using `getProperties().get("fileReference", String.class);` , u need to use getProperties().get("fileReference", String[].class);

Multifield stores values as String array instead of string.